# error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference

Tags: flutter, dart

So for some reason I don't understand the purpose of mounted property. Hope someone could explain it further. Thanks in advance :)
bool get mounted => _element != null;

```
 void getCurrentLocation() async {
    locator.Location location = locator.Location();

    location.getLocation().then(
      (location) {
        currentLocation = location;
      },
    );

    GoogleMapController googleMapController = await _controller.future;

    location.onLocationChanged.listen(
      (newLoc) {
        currentLocation = newLoc;

        googleMapController.animateCamera(
          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
            CameraPosition(
              zoom: 13.5,
              target: LatLng(
                newLoc.latitude!,
                newLoc.longitude!,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );

        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }

        setState(() {});
        // try {
        //   setState(() {});
        //   // } catch (e) {
        // } on Exception catch (e) {
        //   _disposeController();
        // }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly for this case. The widget has been dispose that's why you need to add if (!mounted)

Comment: Can you include a full sample snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: @YeasinSheikh okay update Sir. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: you need to check `mounted` being async method. if you are answering your consider including it on answer section. More about [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot! Sorry it's my first time.